# On generating zip file of realm database its not having all data.

Tags: ios, database, swift, realm

I have an issue with a realm database. I have an app which continues inserts data in the realm database. Now there is a scheduler which creates the a copy of zip file of this realm database in some interval of time. Now the problem is the zip file doesn't get the updated values. I am suspecting the realm's lock file might be preventing it. But I am not sure. Is there any way to get this thing done ?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you're making a backup of Realm file in some interval of time, right? So if you want to include all recent changes to backup you should make sure that all write transactions are committed before you make a copy.

You can also use [-writeCopyToURL:encryptionKey:error:](https://realm.io/docs/objc/1.0.0/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMRealm(im)writeCopyToURL:encryptionKey:error:) method to copy Realm to a temporary destination and then compress it if you need.